# If $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0\leq a<\frac{1}{n}, ~\forall ~n\in \mathbb{N}$, show that $a=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

If $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0\leq a<\frac{1}{n}, ~\forall ~n\in \mathbb{N}$, show that $a=0$.

I can prove it by sandwich rule (squeeze lemma) of limits. But I want to use the concept of Real Number system only rather than the concept of limit.
Please help.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423107/archimedean-proof)

Comment: Maybe do you mean $a=0$?

Comment: Check your post please. Something lacking!

Comment: @EugenCovaci Yes. I heave edited. Thanks.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan  Thanks. I have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Let $\epsilon>0$. Then by the Archimedean Property, there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. Thus,
$0\leq a<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon.$
Thus, $0\leq a<\epsilon \quad \forall \epsilon >0$. Hence, $0\leq a\leq 0$. Thus, $a=0$.

**Solution 2:** We know that 
$$0\leq a\tag 1$$
and
$$a<\frac{1}{n}\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N\tag 2.$$
 Suppose that $0<a$. Then, Archimedean Property says that 
$$\frac{1}{n}<a\quad\text{for some }n\in\Bbb N\tag 3.$$
Statement $(2)$ contradicts statement $(3)$. Therefore, we cannot assume that $0<a$. Because statement $(1)$ is true and $0<a$ is false, it follows that $0=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a \ne 0$. Because $a \ge 0$ from hypothesis it follows $a \gt 0$. Now let's take $n = [\frac 1a] + 1$ where [] is the integer part. We have $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and it's easy to show that $\frac 1n \lt a$, which contradicts the hypothesis.